# XCode swift app runs first time, all subsequent times stuck on launch screen

Tags: swift, xcode

Why does this happen? Initially when I run the app from XCode (developed in swift) on my iPhone SE, it runs fine, but all the other times, it just freezes on launch screen (splash screen). I installed the existing Twilio chat client app in swift. Any advice?

This is code from AppDelegate.swift (other methods in this delegate are all empty):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    MessagingManager.sharedManager().presentLaunchScreen()
    MessagingManager.sharedManager().presentRootViewController()
    return true
}
```

This is the method presentLaunchScreen in MessagingManager:

```
func presentLaunchScreen() {
    presentViewController(controller: storyBoardWithName(name: "LaunchScreen").instantiateInitialViewController()!)
}
```

This is the method presentRootViewController in MessagingManager:

```
func presentRootViewController() {
    if (!hasIdentity) {
        presentViewControllerByName(viewController: "LoginViewController")
        return
    }
    
    if (!connected) {
        connectClientWithCompletion { success, error in
            print("Delegate method will load views when sync is complete")
            if (!success || error != nil) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.presentViewControllerByName(viewController: "LoginViewController")
                }
            }
        }
        return
    }
    
    presentViewControllerByName(viewController: "RevealViewController")
}
```

This is method connectClientWithCompletion in MessagingManager:

```
func connectClientWithCompletion(completion: @escaping (Bool, NSError?) -> Void) {
    if (client != nil) {
        logout()
    }
    
    requestTokenWithCompletion { succeeded, token in
        if let token = token, succeeded {
            self.initializeClientWithToken(token: token)
            completion(succeeded, nil)
        }
        else {
            let error = self.errorWithDescription(description: "Could not get access token", code:301)
            completion(succeeded, error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sharing some code would be useful.

Comment: I am using Swift client from Twilio.

Comment: @Václav I shared some of the code.

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic what is version of Twillio SDK you are using. What is swift version you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the line

```
MessagingManager.sharedManager().presentLaunchScreen()
```

solved the issue for me. But, this is just removing altogether the LaunchScreen, which is nice to have. I will consider other answers for a while here.